# Unsubscribe all listeners from Observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to Observables and Typescript so this might be a rookie question. I want to build a simple timer but I want to be able to unsubscribe all subscribers within the timer itself.

My code so far, looks like this.

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

export class Timer {

    private interval: number;
    private ticker: Observable<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.interval = 1000; // Miliseconds
        this.ticker = Observable.interval(this.interval).timeInterval();
    }

    complete() {
        // Unsubscribe all listeners
    }
}
```

How can I unsubsribe all listeners from `complete` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unsubscribe observers yourself if you don't have their `Subscription` objects (returned from `.subscribe()` calls).

However, you can do it the other way around and instead complete the source Observable using the `takeUntil` operator which will dispose the chain and unsubscribe all observers.

```
constructor() {
  this.end = new Subject();

  this.ticker = Observable.interval(this.interval)
    .takeUntil(this.end)
    .timeInterval();
}

...

complete() {
  this.end.next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @martin, does this also call complete method on subscribers?

Comment: @intelis Yes it will because it completes the chain.